# How can I get All nodes from a .pod file in Cocos3D

Tags: iphone, ios, 3d, cocos3d

The .pod files I am using dont have clearly named nodes, son I CAN'T use:
CC3MeshNode *meshNode = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed:@"NodeName"];

I want to store the full content of the .pod file in a meshNode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i know that this is an old thread and the asker has possibly gotten his answer by now. But hopefully this will help others

[1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271197/cocos-3d-pod-file-format-for-iphone-developing[1]

Answer (score 0):

this is how i got it, replace your initialize function with this code
`
-(void) initializeScene {

```
CC3Camera* cam = [CC3Camera nodeWithName: @"Camera"];

cam.location = cc3v( 0.0, 0.0, 0.6 );

[self addChild: cam];

CC3Light* lamp = [CC3Light nodeWithName: @"Lamp"];
lamp.location = cc3v( -2.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
lamp.isDirectionalOnly = NO;
    [cam addChild: lamp];




CC3PODResourceNode *testBox = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeWithName:@"obj"];

testBox.resource = [CC3PODResource resourceFromFile: @"angry4.POD"];

[self addChild:testBox];





[testBox getNodeNamed: @"obj"].visible = YES;


testBox.touchEnabled = YES;

[testBox setRotation:cc3v(100, 0, 0)];

testBox.location = cc3v(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

[testBox setScale:cc3v(0.5,0.5,0.5)];


CCActionInterval* LCLoop = [CC3Animate actionWithDuration: 4.1];

 [testBox runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:LCLoop]];

[self createGLBuffers];
[self selectShaderPrograms];
[self createBoundingVolumes];

LogInfo(@"The structure of this scene is: %@", [self structureDescription]);
```

}`